# Firebase security rules allows authenticated users to add but never modify

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have just added security rules to my Firebase project such that reading is public and writing is only permitted for authenticated users. This is the rules' json on Firebase:

```
 {
 "rules": {
    "Country" :{
      ".read": "true",
      ".write": "auth !== null",
  }       
 } 
}
```

There is no problem with reading at all. Writing, however, cannot be done unless a new parent is added; I use db.push() and it works greatly. Whenever some modification on data that already exists is done I get "Permission denied" in the logcat.

I have tried to do the following but it still doesn't work:

```
{
 "rules": {
    "Country" :{
      ".read": "true",
      ".write": "auth !== null && (data.exists() || !data.exists())",
  }       
 } 
}
```

How might this issue be solved? it will be really tiresome to delete every data the user needs to modify and re-pushing it since the application is really huge.

Comment: Please post the Android code you are using to perform an update, along with an extract of the relevant messages/errors from your logcat.

Comment: When you say *unless a new parent is added* do you mean a child node of the Country node? i.e. Country/child_0, Country/child_1 etc?

Comment: `data.exists() || !data.exists()` is always `true`